# Is there a way to get the mac addresses and ip of each router connected to a switch?

Tags: c#, windows, networking, router

[image: Setup Of Routers and Switch]

Like what the title says, is there a way to get the mac addresses and/or ip of all routers connected to a switch in asp.net c#?

If so, is there a way to determine if the connected router is on and off?

The setup of my routers and switch is in the image link.

Comment: sorry for the image link.. im new here and i dont know how to properly attach an image

Comment: To a layer-2 device like a switch, a router is just another host with a MAC address. The switch has no idea how to distinguish a router from a PC, printer, etc.

Comment: Well is there a way for me to know if a router is "on" if it is connected to a switch? I'm trying to program something in asp .net c# and looking for a way to do this.. so far i have no luck in doing so.

Comment: You could try to ping the router's IP address. You could ARP for the router's IP address to get the router's MAC address. If you know the switch port on which the router is connected, you may be able to query the switch for the port state using something like SNMP, and you may be able to query the switch for the MAC address table, but the switch won't know the IP addresses. In any event, you will need to know how many routers, their addresses, and maybe how they are connected.

Answer (score 0):

Managed switches uses SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) where you can get information such as the port connection for every port, see [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/44800-mactoport44800.html).

Some more information you can get via LLDP (Link Layer Discovery Protocol), see [here](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos13.3/topics/reference/command-summary/show-lldp-neighbors.html)

I think this should be enough hints. For some work you can use pcap via c#.